# How can I loop through two sets of numbers?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I've got two small puzzles that I can't quite figure out!

I need to loop through two sets of numbers indefinitely, one first and then the other with a 10 second pause between each one in which both values go back to -1. Both start at -1 and both go up to 2.

```
firstIndex = -1
secondIndex = -1
```

I can loop through the first number using:

```
setInterval(() => {
  if (firstIndex === 2) {
    firstIndex = 0;
  } else {
    firstIndex++
  }
}, 10000);
```

But I can't figure out how to switch between the values.

So the results would be…

```
-1, -1 (10 secs) starting values
0, -1 (10 secs)
-1, -1 (10 secs) back to start
1, -1 (10 secs)
-1, -1 (10 secs) back to start
2, -1 (10 secs)
-1, -1 (10 secs) back to start
-1, 0 (10 secs)
-1, -1 (10 secs) back to start
-1, 1 (10 secs)
-1, -1 (10 secs) back to start
-1, 2 (10 secs)
-1, -1 (10 secs) back to start
…and repeat
```

Please help :)

And if it's possible (!) would it also be able to create a loop to switch from left to right like this…

```
-1, -1 (10 secs) starting values
0, -1 (10 secs)
-1, -1 (10 secs) back to start
-1, 0 (10 secs)
-1, -1 (10 secs) back to start
1, -1 (10 secs)
-1, -1 (10 secs) back to start
-1, 1 (10 secs)
-1, -1 (10 secs) back to start
2, -1 (10 secs)
-1, -1 (10 secs) back to start
-1, 2 (10 secs)
-1, -1 (10 secs) back to start
…and repeat
```

Comment: Why are you using a `setInterval()` here? And you need to loop through to sets of numbers? Can you provide those?. Are these *sets of numbers* arrays and you have to indefinitely loop over one, then the other then the first again and so on? Or is it just increasing a counter/ index? In that case my question is why two counters/ indices and not just increase one and set it back to beginning?

Comment: Forget the `setInterval()` part :D

Comment: No, _remove it_ from your post. :) Please see [ask].

Comment: Sorry I should add that the interval is because the incrimination should only happen every 10 seconds :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store those indices in an array instead of two variables. That way it is easily extensible to 3 or more indices.

Here is an implementation where there are 3 instead of 2 indices (to better demo the idea). At any start of the timer callback there will be only one index that is not equal to -1:

```js
var max = 2;
var indices = [-1, -1, max]; // put max in last entry

setInterval(() => {
    let i = indices.findIndex(n => n !== -1);
    indices[i]++;
    if (indices[i] > max) {
        indices[i] = -1;
        indices[(i + 1) % indices.length] = 0;
    }
    console.log(...indices);
}, 300);
```

The assignments in this code make the update to array elements. Realise that an array is used here instead of two (or more) index variables (`firstIndex`, `secondIndex`), as this is better practice.

So use `indices[0]` where you would have used `firstIndex` and `indices[1]` where you would have used `secondIndex`.

If you really, really want to use those to variables, then initialise them every time an update is made, like this (here we use just two indices instead of the three above):

```js
var max = 2;
var indices = [-1, max]; // put max in last entry

setInterval(() => {
    let i = indices.findIndex(n => n !== -1);
    indices[i]++;
    if (indices[i] > max) {
        indices[i] = -1;
        indices[(i + 1) % indices.length] = 0;
    }
    let [firstIndex, secondIndex] = indices;
    console.log(firstIndex, secondIndex);
}, 300);
```

### Switching left and right

As you added another scenario to your question, here are some observations:

- We can use a helper variable `i` that increments by 1, starting with 0
- When that index is *even* (not odd), then the output should always be -1, -1
- When that index is *odd*, one of the indices should be different from -1.
- As that index toggles from side to the other, and this happens every two steps, the "side" (first or second) is determined by the *half* of `i`. When that half is *even*, we need to make the first index different from -1, otherwise the second index.
- The actual value for that index should be `i/4` (integer division), as we can see that it takes 4 more "iterations" to have that same index get a value that is one step incremented.

Here is how that can be achieved:

```js
var max = 2;
var indices = [-1, -1];
var i = 0; // This is the state that determines the 

setInterval(() => {
    index = (i >> 1) % 2;
    if (i % 2 == 0) {  // Every two times, output is -1 -1
        indices[1 - index] = -1;
    } else {
        indices[index] = i >> 2;
    }
    let [firstIndex, secondIndex] = indices;
    console.log(firstIndex, secondIndex);
    i = (i + 1) % ((max + 1) * 4);
}, 300);
```

Comment: These are both great and helpful thank you!

How would I then update the values of firstIndex and secondIndex?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The assignments in this code make the update. But, you should realise that both solutions use *arrays*, as that is better practice than using two variables. So we are saying: don't use two separate variables (`firstIndex`, `secondIndex`), but use an array, which manages both indices. So use `indices[0]` as if you would use `firstIndex` and use `indices[1]` as if you would use `secondIndex`.

Comment: If you just need 2 indices, then of course define `indices = [-1, max]` in the code above (only 2 entries instead of 3). And if you really, really want to have `firstIndex` and `secondIndex` as variables (not best practice), then add this line: `let [firstIndex, secondIndex] = indices` where you need it (inside the `setInterval` callback).

Comment: Added this clarification in my answer as well. Let me know if this answers your comment.

Comment: That works exactly @trincot thank you for updating your answer!

Comment: Ah, sorry! During the 10 second pause, both firstIndex and secondIndex should be -1, and then after 10 seconds the count continues.

So,

`-1, -1
0, -1
(10 seconds)
-1, -1
(10 seconds)
1, -1
(10 seconds)
-1, -1
(10 seconds)
-1, 0
(10 seconds)
-1, -1
(10 seconds)
-1, 1
(10 seconds)
-1, -1
(10 seconds)
-1, 2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243515/discussion-between-stevensunsunsun-and-trincot).

Comment: I'm sorry but I need to be out for the rest of the day. I will come back to this.

Comment: I am trying to understand this changed logic. So it seems every next time you want to come back to `-1 -1`. I don't understand still why the first index now never becomes 2. Could you also update your question, because there you are asking for a different output?

Comment: Hi, yes of course … please see the revised question. Sorry that I wasn't very clear in my first attempt! Thank you!

Comment: I added a solution for that to my answer. If you have more variants you want to ask about, I suggest you first try yourself, and if you cannot make it work, then ask a new question, as a question on Stack Overflow should really be about *one* problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array and increment the value with a given index until a max value and change the index for incrementing the other inddex, and so on.

```js
let
    data = [0, 0],
    index = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    if (++data[index] > 2) {
        data[index] = 0;
        index = 1 - index;
    }
    console.log(...data);
}, 500);
```

Comment: These are both great and helpful thank you!

How would I then update the values of firstIndex and secondIndex?